# SearchView in Actionbar with Realtime Filtered

Tags: android, searchview

I and using ActionBar with ViewPager. I have implemented SearchView and it works when I touch The search icon and It shows Result in SearchResult Activity When I submit the search.

I want to Show search Result Realtime as I Type in search View?

How to Achieve Realtime Search Realtime

I want to replicate Viber like search in Android

Comment: show your code.